# How to describe all faces at point?

Tags: faces, font-lock

When I do `M-x describe-face`, the default face is, according to the doc,

> "the faces of the character after point"

However, looking at the `*Fancy Diary Entries*` buffer, I see many
different colors, and `M-x describe-face` offers the `diary-button` as
the default for *some* characters that have *different* colors (and the
`sample` in the `*Help*` buffer for one of them does *not* match its
appearance).

Moreover, `(get-char-property (point) 'face)` returns `diary-button` for
both of those characters and `(face-at-point nil t)` returns
`(diary-button)` for them too.

So, how come two characters in the same buffer have different colors but
the same faces?

Comment: It might be using overlays, which is a different system than text properties for highlighting text?

Comment: You can use the package https://github.com/Lindydancer/face-explorer to do a more in-depth analysis of the faces in the buffer. It should be able to inspect both text properties and overlays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-char`

That doesn't have a default key binding, but `what-cursor-position` (which does) shows the same information if you pass its DETAIL argument:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>